# How to get join result using mongoose populate, match (2 collections)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

User Schema

```
var UsersSchema = new Schema({
username:String,
city:String
},{collection:'User'});
 //sample data {'username':'7700010000',city:'mumbai'}
```

College Schema

```
var College = new Schema({
    college:String,
    user_sess:[type:String,ref:"User"]},{collection:'College'});
    //sample data {'college':'adarsh college','user_sess':'Sess$7700010000'}
```

I am trying to get result from college collection based on user_sess. but problem is user_sess has value with prefix value 'Sess$'

so ***user_sess*** =  prefix + ***username*** from collection **User**

```
   var prefix = 'Sess$';
   College
    .find({ "user_sess": prefix + req.body.user_id})
    .populate({'user_sess'})
    .exec(function (err, users) {
        console.log();
    if (err)
    res.send(err);
    res.json(users);
    });
```

If there is a match for user_sess then result should look like

```
    {'college':'adarsh college','username':'7700010000','city':'mumbai'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it by adding reference keys in my respective collection because I i tried regex but it added extra latency in my responses. We are using parse server framework but we want to get rid of it but since parse saves data differently I was not able to do joins using mongoose schema.

Thank you.